# Network Flows - a cut

Tags: network, network-flow

A really simple question that I cannot find a direct answer to.  I guess it's considered so obvious but when finding a cut on a network flow graph (not necessarily min) can it cut an arc twice? TY

Comment: A cut is simply a partition of the vertices into two sets such that the source is in one and the sink is in the other.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe because I hadn't come across any such examples before where I need to cut an arc twice to be able to separate the network into two (in my case given) sets I wrongly assumed that it has to be once only.